# Where can I find data about Cameroons subdivisions and number of inhabitants?

Tags: census

I want to know where I can find detailed, current and authoritative (ie. government) data about all of Cameroons [subdivisions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subdivisions_of_Cameroon) and the number of inhabitants in each (ie. [census data](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Census)).

I know that Cameroon is divided into 10 [regions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regions_of_Cameroon), which are in turn divided into [departments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Departments_of_Cameroon), which are in turn divided into [communes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Communes_of_Cameroon), which in turn consist of villages, and even neighborhoods have their names. Often names exist in English as well as French. I want to know the official names of all of them and the number of people living in each.

I have come across a number of documents online (but am not allowed to post links to them):

- United Councils and Cities of Cameroon (official but incomplete)
- Village Dictionary of Donga-Mantung Division (official but neither current nor complete)
- Joshua Project (inofficial and neither current nor complete)

Data for the [Northwest Region](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Northwest_Region_(Cameroon)) and it's subdivisions is of particular interest to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Répertoire actualisé des villages du Cameroun](http://www.ceped.org/ireda/inventaire/ressources/cmr-2005-rec_v4.7_repertoire_actualise_villages_cameroun.pdf) provides

- authoritative (Centre Population et Développement, Université Paris Descartes, Institut de Recherche pour le Développement),
- detailed (Régions > Départements > Arrondissement > Quartiers / Villages) and
- current (2005)

data about the number of inhabitants for all subdivisions of Cameroon.

Answer (score 2):

You can use GADM:

http://gadm.org/

For Cameroon there are 4 levels:

- Level 0 the country border
- Level 1 region
- level 2 departement
- level 3 Arrondissement

http://gadm.org/download

In order to get the population per level you can take two approaches:

1. use a global dataset such as gridded population of the world and calculate zonal statistics. http://sedac.ciesin.columbia.edu/data/collection/gpw-v4
2. Try to find a local census and join the tabular data to the shapefile attribute table. http://cameroon.opendataforafrica.org/rfdefze/census-data

Comment: Unfortunately GADM does not provide any data below the level of Arrondissement.